# Dump Data from bigquery to postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, google-bigquery

I have about the 3GB 4-5 table in google bigquery and I want to export these table to Postgres. Reading the docs I found I have to do following steps.

1. create a job that will extract data to CSV in the google bucket.
2. From google storage to local storage.
3. Parse all CSV to database

So in the above step is there any efficient way to do all this. I know that step 1 and 2 can't skip no chance of efficiency but in step 3 from reading online, i found that it will take 2-3 hours to do this process.

Can anyone suggest me an efficient way to do this

Answer (score 0):

Make an example project and see what times you get, if you can accept those times it's too early to optimize. I see all this is possible in about 3-5 minutes if you have 1Gbit internet access and server running on SSD.